# Joining strings with a list of lists if they meet a specific condition

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, indexing

I have this list of lists:

```
x = [["hello", 1, "pacific", 'M','F','W'], ["yes", 4, 5, "turn", 'S', 'F', 'Su']]
```

I would like to join specific items in the list: 'M','F','W','S','Su'

So if any of these items exist in the list they should be joined together resulting in:

```
x = [["hello", 1, "pacific", 'M,F,W'], ["yes", 4, 5, "turn", 'S,F,Su']]
```

**My Current attempt looks like this:**

```
x = [["hello", 1, "pacific", 'M','F','W'], ["yes", 4, 5, "turn", 'S', 'F', 'Su']]

z = []

for item in x: 

    for y in item:

        if y == 'M' or y == 'F' or y =='W' or y == 'S' or y =='Su':

            item.index(y)

            z.append((item.index(y)))

        else:
            pass

x[min(z):max(z)+1] = [','.join(item[min(z):max(z)+1])]

print(x)
```

I thought I could grab the positions of the specific strings I want in the list and then join them using min and max.

My code returns:

```
[['hello', 1, 'pacific', 'M', 'F', 'W'], ['yes', 4, 5, 'turn', 'S', 'F', 'Su'], 'turn,S,F']
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Would they always occur in last three positions?

Comment: Will they always be consecutive?

Comment: I would prefer if they were not forced to be in the final position. It is possible they would not always be in the final positions... thats a good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one liner list comprehension:

```
[[i for i in sublist if i not in l] + [','.join([i for i in sublist if i in l])] for sublist in x]
```

Output:

```
[['hello', 1, 'drugs', 'M,F,W'], ['yes', 4, 5, 'turn', 'S,F,Su']]
```

Full code:

```
x = [["hello", 1, "drugs", 'M','F','W'], ["yes", 4, 5, "turn", 'S', 'F', 'Su']]
l = ['M', 'F', 'W', 'S', 'Su']
print([[i for i in sublist if i not in l] + [','.join([i for i in sublist if i in l])] for sublist in x])
```

This just loops through the list and in each sublist it extracts all strings that are not in the `l` list, and adds a value as a last element which is a string with the strings in the sublist which are also in the `l` list joined and separated by commas.

### Edit:

Due to knowing that the specific items are not going to be always at the end, you could try using `itertools.takewhile` and `itertools.dropwhile`.

I modified your list a bit (moving location of the specific items), to prove that my code works:

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile
x = [["hello", 1, 'M','F','W', "drugs"], ["yes", 4, 5, 'S', 'F', 'Su', "turn"]]
l = ['M', 'F', 'W', 'S', 'Su']
newlist = []
for sublist in x:
    b = list(takewhile(lambda x: x not in l, sublist))
    newlist.append(b + [','.join([i for i in sublist if i in l])] + list(dropwhile(lambda x: x in l, sublist[len(b):])))
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[['hello', 1, 'M,F,W', 'drugs'], ['yes', 4, 5, 'S,F,Su', 'turn']]
```

It works as expected.

Comment: This will cause the "M, F, W" portion to always be at the end of the list, even if it occurred in the middle of the original list

Comment: I've been trying to do this for 4 hours.... I feel... incredibly grateful thank you

Comment: @BlastOffBronze Yeah in the OP's example it's all at the end.

Comment: @SamSchneider Your welcome, please accept and upvote if it helps :)

Comment: @U11-Forward is there a way to keep them in the same position rather than moving them to the end?

Comment: @BlastOffBronze any way to maintain its original position in the list if it was in the middle of the list>

Comment: @SamSchneider Are the values to join always be in consecutive order?

Comment: @U11-Forward yes they will always be in consecutive order

Comment: @SamSchneider Trying to do it wait a sec

Comment: @SamSchneider Done!, Please check the edit section.

Comment: Your solution with `takewhile` and `dropwhile` does not work when there are two groups of consecutive items matching the special keys. And by using `sublist[sublist.index(b[-1]) + 1:]` the code would fail when the last item of the special group appears more than once in the list.

Comment: @blhsing Let me ask the OP

Comment: @SamSchneider Will there be any cases where there would be 2 sets of special characters?

Comment: My second point should read: And by using `sublist[sublist.index(b[-1]) + 1:]` the code would fail when the last item in the first group `b` appears more than once in the list. For example, try: `x = [[1, "hello", 1, 'M','F','W', "drugs"]]`, which outputs `[[1, 'hello', 1, 'M,F,W', 'hello', 1, 'M', 'F', 'W', 'drugs']]` with your code.

Comment: @blhsing Edited my answer, the second point you mentioned should be solved now.

Comment: Why use `index(b[-1])` at all? `b[::-1].index(b[-1])` is always going to be `0` since the last character of a string is always going to be at index 0 when you reverse the string.

Comment: @blhsing Ouch I am over-complicating it. Will edit

Comment: @blhsing Edited mine

Answer (score 1):

You can try `set`

```py
[[*set(i).difference([ 'M','F','W','S','Su']), ','.join(set(i).intersection([ 'M','F','W','S','Su']))] for i in x]
```

```
[['hello', 1, 'pacific', 'F,W,M'], ['yes', 4, 5, 'turn', 'F,S,Su']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group together consecutive items that belong to one of the key items you're looking for so you can join them into a comma-delimited string while leaving the other items separate:

```
from itertools import groupby

x = [
    ["hello", 1, 'M', 'F', 'W', "pacific", "S", "Su", "no"],
    ["yes", 4, 5, "turn", 'S', 'F', 'Su']
]
keys = {'M', 'F', 'W', 'S', 'Su'}
print([
    [
        i
        for k, g in groupby(lst, keys.__contains__)
        for i in ([','.join(g)] if k else g)
    ] for lst in x
])
```

This outputs:

```
[['hello', 1, 'M,F,W', 'pacific', 'S,Su', 'no'], ['yes', 4, 5, 'turn', 'S,F,Su']]
```